# save files from android app to google drive without using HTTP request

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I want to save files from my Android application to Google drive, but i don't want to use HTTPS request. I want to put my files in Google drive even if the user is offline like local drive. So when user will come online, Google drive will upload this file to cloud automatically.

Is there any api exist who let upload files while offline?
Is there any same APIs for iOS also??

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

There is no API to interact with the Google Drive Clients in the way that you want, sorry! However, it is as easy as doing a copy or move operation on the file system. Just ask and store the user's Google Drive location on the disk, then copy the file into that directory when you need to.

Answer (score 0):

For people digging in the Stackoverflow archives, note that offline drive access is available using the Google Drive API for Android. See the documentation here: https://developers.google.com/drive/android/ ... and for sure there must be one for iOS too.